# Decrease drag threshold with tablet in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, tablet, cursor, drag-and-drop

I'm using Windows 7 with a a Wacom Intuos 3 tablet.

When clicking and dragging, the drag action doesn't seem to be recognized until the cursor has travelled a certain distance, roughly 15-20 pixels. This makes it really annoying to select small areas like a single character of text.

Is this normal behaviour, and is there a way to decrease or disable this drag threshold?